# Push not-new local branch to remote

Tags: git

I have read elsewhere that you can add a *new* local branch to remote by this command:

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```

The catch here is, my local branch is not *new* in the sense it has several local commits, but is new to the remote. Will my remote have the local branch and its commit history if I use the same command? If not, what should I use instead?

Comment: I think the word "new" here is tripping you up. AFAIK the answer is _yes_.

Comment: One important thing: if you already have upstream set, you don't need `-u` flag when you push. And one more: you can use `HEAD` instead of branch name, so you don't have to remember the branch name or misspell its name.

Answer (score 0):

If I can guess right, I think you have a new local branch and want to push to a remote branch. If that is the case then you can follow this pattern `git push  <REMOTENAME> <LOCALBRANCHNAME>:<REMOTEBRANCHNAME>` This pushes the LOCALBRANCHNAME to your REMOTENAME, but it is renamed to REMOTEBRANCHNAME.

Answer (score 0):

What `git push` really does is call up some other Git, supply it with commits (and any other required objects) if/as necessary, and then ask that other Git to set—possibly creating or deleting, in the process—some branch and/or tag names to some commit hash IDs.

What's in *your* repository is almost irrelevant to this process.  The only real constraint your own Git imposes is that the hash IDs it's going to supply to the other Git, at the end where it makes requests for them to update *their* names, must be valid hash IDs in your repository.  You can, and usually do, produce these valid hash IDs by supplying *your* name(s) for branches or tags, but that's not strictly required.

As [Nemanja Glumac noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722130/push-not-new-local-branch-to-remote#comment94298195_53722130), you can use `HEAD` as a name on your side.  If you're currently on one of your own branches, your Git finds your branch name, knows it's a branch, and finds its tip commit and uses that as the commit hash ID it will ask the other Git to use.  Then, before it asks the other Git to set anything, it makes sure the other Git has that commit and any predecessor commits required to complete that commit's history.  Then it asks the other Git to set one of *its* branch names or tags to the hash ID.

The default is usually to ask the other Git to use the same name that you used on your side, but you can change this with the `push.default` setting.  So:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2:newbranch tag3 a123456:refs/heads/tag4 :del
```

has your Git call up another Git at `origin`, transfer any commits (and anything else) required to that Git if needed, then ask their Git to:

- set their `branch1` branch name to match yours;
- set their `newbranch` branch name to match your `branch2` branchname;
- set their `tag3` tag to match your `tag3` tag (assuming `tag3` is a tag);
- set their `tag4` tag to point to commit (or other object) whose hash ID is `a123456...`; and
- delete their name `del` (whether that's a branch or a tag).

Every name after `origin` here is a *refspec*, which is roughly "two names separated by colon", except that you can omit the colon and the second name to mean "re-use the first name".

They are allowed to reject any or all of these requests, for any reason they might choose.  If they *do* reject the requests, you can try again with a more forceful request using `--force` or a plus-sign prefix on one or more of the refspecs.  They may still reject these more-forceful commands; again, it's up to *their* Git to decide.

The default, though, is generally to accept polite branch update requests when those updates:

- create a *new* branch on their end;
- *delete* a branch on their end; or
- move their existing branch name in what Git calls a *fast-forward* operation.

In modern Git, tag updates are refused by default, but very old receiving Gits accidentally applied the branch rules here.